# Ruby on Rails redirection from middleware with POST, PUT methods, it redirect me to Index instead of Show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, puma

Hey I am trying to make an admin portal with 3 different styles but using the same controllers

I wanted and managed to make my URL look like the following:

```
www.localhost.com/admin
www.localhost.com/prefixA/admin
www.localhost.com/prefixB/admin
```

and in each request, I detect the URL prefix and render the corresponding styles to it.

everything working right and all of them use controllers as I wanted them to be.

my routes look like the following:

```
# config.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  extend AdminPortal
end

# config/routes/admin_portal.rb
module AdminPortal
  def self.extended(router)
    router.instance_exec do
      extend AdminRoutes
      extend PrefixAAdminRoutes
      extend PrefixBAdminRoutes
    end
  end
end

# config/routes/base_admin_routes.rb
module BaseAdminRoutes
  def self.extended(router)
    router.instance_exec do
      namespace :admin do
        # Routes goes here
      end
    end
  end
end

# config/routes/admin_routes.rb
module AdminRoutes
  def self.extended(router)
    router.instance_exec do
      extend BaseAdminRoutes
    end
  end
end


# config/routes/prefix_a_admin_routes.rb
module PrefixAAdminRoutes
  def self.extended(router)
    router.instance_exec do
      resource :prefix_a do
        extend BaseAdminRoutes
      end
    end
  end
end

# config/routes/prefix_b_admin_routes.rb
module PrefixBAdminRoutes
  def self.extended(router)
    router.instance_exec do
      resource :prefix_b do
        extend BaseAdminRoutes
      end
    end
  end
end
```

my problem now is how to keep a certain prefix all along, if my URL on `prefix_a` i wanted to keep using it while moving in the admin panel, and if I am using `prefix_b` and open tab it opens the link with `prefix_b` appended to URL.

I tried to do so within middleware:

```
class AdminPanelSwitcher
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    @status, @headers, _ = @app.call(env)

    if request.path.include? '/admin'
        env = portal_redirect env, request, PortalHelper::PREFIX_A
        env = portal_redirect env, request, PortalHelper::PREFIX_B
        _, _, @response = @app.call(env)
    end

    [@status, @headers, @response]
  end

  def portal_redirect(env, request, portal_prefix)
    if request.referer and request.referer.include? portal_prefix
      unless request.path.include? portal_prefix
        %w[ORIGINAL_FULLPATH PATH_INFO REQUEST_PATH REQUEST_URI].each do |req|
          env[req] = request.path.sub('admin', "#{portal_prefix}/admin")
        end
        @headers['Location'] = env['PATH_INFO']
        @status = 301
      end
    end
    env
  end
end
```

it works perfectly only in `GET` requests, but in `POST, PUT, PATCH` requests, it behaves weirdly
it redirects me to `index` instead of `show` all the time, so is there's a better solution than this, or I am missing something in my middleware that missing it up for me.